# Can't enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular, cors, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Angular 2 service making a call to an ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API Controller Class  but I get this error:

[image]

**card.service.ts:** Angular 2 code. This runs on `http://localhost:3000`. I doubt there is a problem here.

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Http, Response } from 'angular2/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { ICard } from './card';

@Injectable()
export class CardService {
    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getCards(): Observable<ICard[]> {
        return this._http.get('http://localhost:8462/api/card')
            .map((response: Response) => <ICard[]>response.json())
            .do(data => console.log("getCards: " + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')
    }    
}
```

**Startup.cs:** ASP.NET Core code. Runs on `http://localhost:8462`. I believe the fix is to add CORS to my Startup.cs file. I've tried following the [ASP.NET docs on CORS](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cors.html), as well as many other CORS guides with no luck.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddCors();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

        app.StaticFiles();

        app.UseCors(builder =>
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
            );

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, I just tried that and it works fine for me. Can you show how you call the webservice? Can you also try it without Angular 2’s `http` library (which has proven to be somewhat odd in the past); something like `fetch('http://localhost:8462/api/card', { mode: 'cors' })`. Also, check the network tab to see whether the service actually sends out any CORS related headers. Also also, what version of ASP.NET Core are you running on? Is this RC1 or are you running some dev builds (I only tested the latter now)? And are you running this through IIS, or using Kestrel directly from the command line?

Comment: I made the same call using Fiddler. Got a similar 401 error. I am running on ASP.NET RC1. I am running it through IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. When I first did File > New Project I selected Windows Authentication. It looks like that is what is causing the error.

I tested it by creating a new project with Windows Authentication and adding CORS to Startup.cs. Got the same error. Did not get the error when I created a new project without Windows Authentication and added CORS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues. My trick was to put the "UseCors.." before "UseMvc()" :-)